# Application variable always references my object, I want it to keep a "copy"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

maybe its been a long day, but I just cant figure this out.

I retrieve a large custom object from WCF, and store it in an application variable.
This happens every 20 minutes.

For each web user, I am checking the existence and timeout of this application variable, and if needed, re-query my wcf and build a new object, and re-store it in the application variable.

**This all good and well.**

Now, I am trying to "make a copy" of this "master" object, modify it, and store it in a session variable, modifying it as needed throughout the session life cycle. (modifying the session variable).

Everytime I modify the session object, the object in the application variable gets modified.

**Pseudo**

```
application("mastervar") = object from wcf (obejct type - xcustomclass)

dim mynewobject as new xcustomclass
mynewobject = application("mastervar")
```

***** Modifying mynewobject, also modifies application("mastervar")

**I have tried:**

```
session("mynewSessionVar") = application("mastervar")
mynewobject = session("mynewSessionVar")
```

Modifying mynewobject, modifies application("mastervar")

**I have tried:**

Manually copying all properties in mastervar object to new object, with a for loop.

```
mycustomobject = new xcustomclass
mycustomobjectObject as new xcustomclass.object

mymasterobject = application("mastervar")

for each object in mymasterobject.objectslist
mycustomobjectObject = new xcustomclass.object

with mycustomobjectObject
  .property = object.property
end with

mycustomobject.objectlist.add(mycustomobjectObject)

next
```

Same thing, modifying mycustomobject, also modifies application("mastervar")

As I said, maybe its been a long day, but I've been bumping my head against this for hours...

#### EDIT

```
 Private Function copy_fresh_units(unitsFromWcf As WebResortUnits) As WebResortUnits
        Dim myFreshUnits As New WebResortUnits
        Dim myFreshUnit As WebResortUnits.qbunit

        For Each Unit In unitsFromWcf.resortUnits
            myFreshUnit = New WebResortUnits.qbunit

            With myFreshUnit

                ' .Availability = Unit.Availability
                .mapDetails = Unit.mapDetails

            End With

          myFreshUnits.resortUnits.Add(Unit)

         Next

return myFreshUnits

End Function
```

Modifying the availability property in myfreshUnits, it still updates the app var. I have had a look at reference and value types, and it is definitely my issue. But taking this alst edit into account, I know I am missing something, what it is, I am not sure... :-)

Comment: Every time you set a custom object to `application("mastervar")`, you're actually setting the object's reference to the the reference for `application("mastervar")`, so when you change your object, you also change the application variable.  Investigate reference vs value, and look into a Clone function for your WCF object that copies all field values but not references into a new object.

Comment: I was under the impression the for loop was cloning... Are you implying that the properties themselves get referenced when doing. newobject.property = masterobject.property ?

Comment: Replied to Kevin's answer with the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a new reference to the objects and then modifying the object that you reference and expecting your two references to not be the same object?

It sounds like what you really want to do is to clone the objects or make a deepcopy of the objects.

If these are custom objects you will need custom code to make a Clone of them.

When you Clone your object be sure that you create a new object and set all of the value types on that new object from your old object.  Then go through and clone all of your reference types and set the reference properties on your clone to point to the clones of the properties you've created.

**EDIT: To address your update**

The problem is still... everything you are copying is obviously a reference type and it's not being cloned.  So there is only one object in existence therefor when you edit either reference it changes the object.

**EDIT 2: Serialization will help you**

Serializing and deserializing your base object in memory is an easy way to clone it.  I generally write a custom clone method that serializes / deserializes the object.  That way you have a Clone() method that you will always call and any custom code you need that doesn't get handled properly with serialize / deserialize you can handle in that method.

Comment: I am trying to "clone" it manually, with the for loop. In the for, I am creating a new custom object, and setting its properties. Are you implying that the properties themselves get referenced when doing. newobject.property = masterobject.property ?

Comment: If the properties are reference types (as opposed to value types) then you need to clone the object that the property references as well.

Comment: Your last set of code has this `mymasterobject = application("mastervar")`, that defeats all of the code underneath it.

Comment: I am doing that -> mymasterobject = application("mastervar") ,to get a workable object to step through, and get its properties to clone into the new fresh object?

Comment: You really need to research reference types vs value types before you spend much more time on this.  That line of code sets your new object to the same reference of your application variable.  It links them so that changes to either `mymasterobject` or `application("mastervar")` will be made to the same reference, being reflected in either variable.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely I agree.  Look into reference vs value types first and a lot if this will be clear.

Comment: Thanks to all so far, I understand what the issue is. But I am still not certain precisely what is happening where. I have now, in the copy property per property function, elected not to copy one property. I.e. copying all properties, one for one, setting new object propeties to existing object properties, but not copying one specific property. This one property not copied in the for loop, still gets referenced back into the app var. I am updating my original Q with an example.

Comment: Regarding your update, am I to understand then that, when initially copying the properties, the new object does not have that one property copied as per my intention. But then modifying this empty property, goes and modifies the complete new object, thereby changing the first object again. If so, I think I understand much better now, thanks. That being said, knowing what is happening, any suggestions on how to achieve my required functionality? I can serialize the object to xml, and read it into a session var every time, but I would rather not want to do HDD access.

Comment: If I create a second class (not instance, totally new class), and copy between the two, will it still point to the same memory location for the copied properties?

Comment: If the property is itself a reference type then you are not really creating a new version of the object that property refers to unless you clone the object that the property refers to.  An easy way for you to clone a complete object graph is to serialize your object in memory and then deserialize it.  However I highly recommend you understand reference vs value types as it's critical to understanding what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: @Kevin , thanks for that. I did end up serializing to xml file, just to get it working. I did not think to serialize it to a memory stream and back... That will address my HDD write concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the properties you are copying are not all primitives themselves (`int`, `float`, `string`, etc). When you then alter the corresponding property on the new object, it is then altering the original property (since it's not a primitive and is really an object reference).

Check out https://github.com/JesseBuesking/BB.DeepCopy which is probably a bit of overkill, but if you read what's under **The problem this addresses** you can see alternative approaches for helping in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I accepted the other more detailed answer, and upvoted yours, as the first paragraph also nails it. Thanks.